# ReactJS check the render method of `Provider` ContextAPI

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Hi I'm trying to use Context API and this is my code

***App.js***

```
import  {Provider}  from './components/contexApi/context';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider>
        <div className="App"> 
          <Header />    
          <TodoList />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my **context.js** file

***context.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const Context = React.createContext;

export class Provider extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>

        )
    }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

After I save the file the main page says:

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `Provider`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.createContext` is a function and you are not calling it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext